# mktemp vs. umask 066 and touch?

Tags: bash, shell, umask, mktemp

My bash shell requires a temp file.  Suppose filename conflict is not an issue, can I say `mktemp` is not as good as manually touch a temp file after `umask 066`?

My assumption is:
mktemp is a system function, compared to manually touch a file, it still takes a little bit more resource.

I've read something about `ln -s etc/passwd` attack, but it looks like a story decades ago when passwords were not shadowed.

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Both `mktemp` and `touch` are external commands that need to be run in separate processes. I see no reason to use `touch` over `mktemp`.

Comment: I just feel mktemp needs to generate a random value which needs calculation.  While touch is pretty straight forward.  In my case, using touch, is uses 209K memory.  And using mktemp, it uses 308K memory.  That's a 50% increase.  I understand nowadays 100k memory is really nothing, just if both can achieve the same thing, why won't I choose the one using less resource.

Answer (score 2):

Those two commands are not destined to do the same thing.  `mktemp` creates a file in a flexible way, and has features to make sure it uses a unique name.  `touch` will modify the timestamp of a file (or create it if it does not exist), but you supply the name.

If you want to create an empty file for which you already have a name, then use `touch` ; if you are going to write to that file right after, you do not need to create it first, just redirect to it.

But if you really need to make a temporary file and ensure you will not overwrite any other file, `touch` does nothing for you.  It is "lighter", maybe, but useless in this case, and you need `mktemp`.

Comment: thank you for your explanation.  Is there any security related advantage for mktemp over umask+touch?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, mktemp creates files that are accessible only by their owner, so I would expect that to be.  You can modify permissions on a file with "chmod" if you are not satisfied with permissions they are created with (and no matter how they are created, touch, mktemp or otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

The mktemp command was written by Todd C. Miller of OpenBSD to prevent common vulnerabilities in shell scripts. In [his own words](https://www.mktemp.org/docs/readme/):

> Mktemp is a simple utility designed to make temporary file handling in
> shells scripts be safe and simple.  Traditionally, people writing
> shell scripts have used constructs like:
>
> ```
> TFILE=/tmp/foop.$$
> ```
>
> which are trivial to attack.  If such a script is run as root it may
> be possible for an attacker on the local host to gain access to the
> root login, corrupt or unlink system files, or do a variety of other
> nasty things.
>
> The basic problem is that most shells have no equivalent to open(2)'s
> O_EXCL flag.  While it is possible to avoid this using temporary
> directories, I consider the use of mktemp(1) to be superior both in
> terms of simplicity and robustness.

Shadow passwords do not help here. If the script is run a root and it writes to a temporary file in an insecure way, then an attacker could possibly exploit race conditions to modify /etc/password or /etc/shadow or both!